# Sphinx SetSortMode EXPR

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to sort using Sphinx (PHP) to show in order of price but when I do it will show £10 before £1.75 so I need to use ABS like in mySQL.

I have tried this:

$s->SetSortMode (SPH_SORT_EXPR, "ABS(display_price) ASC" );

It doesnt seem to work though.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Check, if display_price attribute treated as a decimal in search index

Probably you have

> sql_attr_string = display_price

instead of

> sql_attr_float = display_price

or

> sql_attr_bigint = display_price

- updated

Comment: sphinx does not have a sql_attr_decimal attribute type.

Answer (score 1):

SPH_SORT_EXPR is ALWAYS descending order. the ASC/DESC are for use with EXTENDED mode only.

To 'invert' it to become acsending, can build it into the expression.

```
$s->SetSortMode (SPH_SORT_EXPR, "1000000-CEIL(ABS(display_price*100.0))" );
```